# Reading Xml file in eclipse plugin view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I would like to know how to read and modify an XML file in Eclipse plugin with view template.
I have written the following code inside `createPartControl` method of view class. Upon button click this method shall read xml file but it does not. It throws file not exist error.

Code:

```java
        IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
        IWorkspaceRoot iroot = workspace.getRoot();
        IProject project  = iroot.getProject("samplePlugin");
        IFolder folder = project.getFolder("resources");
        IFile file=folder.getFile("repository.xml");

        if(file.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("File Exists");
            try {
                doc = docBuilder.parse(file.getContents());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File not exists");
             }
```

Anyone please correct my code and let me know where did I make the mistake.

Comment: Well do you have a 'repository.xml' file in the 'resources' folder of a 'samplePlugin' project in the **run time workspace**? When you run your plugin the workspace used is **not** your development workspace. Look in 'Run > Run Configurations' to see where the run time workspace is located.

Comment: Under project it shows "myProject name" and under 'Main Class' field it displays '<project name>.views.JavaGetUrl'. What should I do? Please help greg-449

Comment: On the Main tab look at 'Location' - that is where your run time workspace is located. When you run your plugin I assume you are getting a new Eclipse started - in that Eclipse you will be using this workspace, you need to create projects, folders and files in that workspace.

Comment: This is the location of runtime workspace "${workspace_loc}/../runtime-EclipseApplication" given.

Comment: Yes, you have to create the files you want to read in that workspace.